# Where is NRules documentation gone?

Tags: rule-engine, nrules

Can someone kindly point out where NRules documentation is? The links that I found shown below are all broken.

[Getting-Started](https://github.com/NRules/NRules/wiki/Getting-Started).

[Index](http://nrules.net/api/index.html)

I hope this is not a depreciating project :(

If that is the case what are good alternatives?

Comment: I just got a mail saying that they are now back. Great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nrules-users/jFwLtPlZbmE) post from the author, the project has been removed. There are forks in various states on GitHub, but nothing complete. There are no other active open source .Net Rules engines that I've found, but there are many other commercial alternatives ([InRule](http://www.inrule.com/)).

If you're currently using NRules, I checked in a copy of the API documentation to GitHub [here](https://maoliver.github.io/NRules/NRules/). I do not have a copy of the wiki.

If the implementation language is not a concern -- [Drools](http://www.drools.org/) is one of the best open source rules systems available.

Comment: NRules project is back on [GitHub](https://github.com/NRules/NRules). Here is [wiki](https://github.com/NRules/NRules/wiki) and [API documentation](http://nrules.net/api/index.html)

Comment: Just noticed your comment. Glad to see you're back : ).

Comment: And still going strong with a release for `0.9.0` in May 2019